# want to extract a particular row from csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas

```
Fuel Type,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018
Diesel,7,4,17,43,138,346,681,1412,3206,5976,10364,15514,17253
Diesel-Electric,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,17,23,22,22,21
Electric,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,0,1,1,12,314,560
Petrol,471707,513375,545994,571629,589034,596947,609792,612654,605511,587900,578977,574443,569673
Petrol-CNG,214,248,2440,2678,2706,2642,2410,2253,2100,1932,1682,1006,386
Petrol-Electric,379,1057,1999,2637,3305,3786,4684,5020,5727,6371,10075,20751,27179
Petrol-Electric (Plug-In),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,47,108,125,206,380
```

from above csv file want extract values corresponding to diesel row

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename', sep=",",header=0)
diesel = df[df["Fuel Type"] == 'Diesel']
```

Edit from the comment, to get all rows where Diesel is contained in Fuel Type

```
diesel = df[df["Fuel Type"].str.contains('Diesel')]
```

If you dont want to use pandas, you can also simply use

```
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    if line[:6] == "Diesel":
        break
print(line)
```